# Unable to open Remote Exchange (2010 and 2013) PSSession from a different domain (WinRM) error. Please advise?

Tags: c#, powershell-2.0, exchange-server, powershell-remoting, winrm

I am trying to open a remote exchange PS session and its failing and giving a WinRM error.

Please note that i am able to open normal PS session, but not with exchange configuration.

1. So is it possible to manage an exchange server from any machine in the same domain with PSRemoting enabled?
2. Is it possible to manage exchange server from a machine from different domain?
3. Any suggestions w.r.t errors are welcome?

Here are the commands i executed:

```
**Case 1: Failing to open a remote session with exchange configuration.**

PS C:\> $connectionUri="http://{fqdn/powershell?serializationLevel=Full;ExchClientVer=14.3.91.1"

PS C:\> $s = New-PSSession -ConnectionURI $connectionUri -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange
 -SessionOption $so -Credential $c
[fqdn] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM clie
nt cannot process the request. The WinRM client tried to use Negotiate authentication mechanism, but the destination co
mputer (fqdn:80) returned an 'access denied' error. Change the configuration to allow Negot
iate authentication mechanism to be used or specify one of the authentication mechanisms supported by the server. To us
e Kerberos, specify the local computer name as the remote destination. Also verify that the client computer and the des
tination computer are joined to a domain. To use Basic, specify the local computer name as the remote destination, spec
ify Basic authentication and provide user name and password. Possible authentication mechanisms reported by server: For
 more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [], PSRemotingTransportExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed

Without connectionURL, and with just fqdn:

PS C:\> $s = New-PSSession fqdn -Credential $c -ConfigurationName
Microsoft.Exchange
[fqdn] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WS-Managem
ent service cannot process the request. The resource URI (__http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange) w
as not found in the WS-Management catalog. The catalog contains the metadata that describes resources, or logical endpo
ints. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [], PSRemotingTransportExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed

**Case 2: without exchange configuration, i am able to open the PS session.**

PS C:\> $s = New-PSSession "fqdn" -Credential $c
PS C:\> $s

 Id Name            ComputerName    State    ConfigurationName     Availability
 -- ----            ------------    -----    -----------------     ------------
  1 Session1        xxxxxxxxxxxx       Opened   Microsoft.PowerShell     Available
```

Regards,

Dreamner

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your environment is like, but maybe try these links to setup the CAS for remoting

**Setting up CAS for remote powershell over Internet:**
http://www.parative.com/Blogs/Exchange/2010/02/exchange-2010-remote-powershell/

**Remotely managing Exchange 2010 with Powershell:**
http://www.mikepfeiffer.net/2010/02/managing-exchange-2010-with-remote-powershell/

**Connecting to a remote Exchange 2010 Organization using Remote PowerShell:** http://www.msexchange.org/blogs/walther/news/connecting-to-a-remote-exchange-2010-organization-using-remote-powershell-429.html